# SwiftUI: How can I change the color from the Button in alert?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm new in SwiftUI and I would change the color from the "accept" button in alert if the dark mode is activated. The button should have a different color in light mode than in dark mode.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var alertShouldBeShown = !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "FirstStart")

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        Text("Hello World!")
        
        .alert(isPresented: $alertShouldBeShown, content: {

            Alert(title: Text("Disclaimer"),
                  message: Text("Placeholder"),
                  dismissButton: Alert.Button.default(
                    Text("Accept"), action: {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "FirstStart")
                  }
                )
            )
        })
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color of the alert button is based on the tint/accent color of the app. This color can actually be dynamic for dark and light mode. The easiest way is to define the color in the asset catalog.

In the iOS 14 beta you can define the accent color for SwiftUI within the asset catalog without writing any extra code. If you want this to work in iOS 13 you should probably read [this](https://adampaxton.com/how-to-globally-set-a-tint-or-accent-color-in-swiftui/) article. Use the `UIColor(named: "")` API if you want to use a color from your asset catalog that has different light/dark mode appearance.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK You can't change the text and colours on the built-in `Alert`. You'll have you create your own custom alert.

For example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: { showAlert = true }) {
                Text("Press")
            }
            if showAlert {
                Color.black
                    .opacity(0.1)
                CustomAlert(isPresented: $showAlert, title: "Disclaimer", bodyText: "Placeholder", buttonText: "Accept")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomAlert: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var title: String
    var bodyText: String
    var buttonText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text(title)
                    .bold()
                Text(bodyText)
                Button(action: { self.isPresented = false}) {
                    Text(buttonText)
                        .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .blue : .green)
                }
            }
            .padding(20)
            .background(
                Color.white
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            )
        }
    }
}
```